# How can I send an http request that contains an email in the queries?

Tags: power-automate

I am doing a simple flow that automates an http POST function to do a reservation. The problem is that inside the queries parameter it contains an email and I think this causes problems as it contains an @ symbol and I think it causes trouble as MS uses it as a special character.

The flow is the following.

[image]

And the contents of it are the following.

[image]

I think that the email field is the problem because the error returned by the API says that the email is invalid:

[image]

I've tested the API quite a bit with some python code and as far as I know this error is only returned when the email field is incorrect.

Also I've tried saving the email in a variable and calling it from the email field inside the query with no luck. See:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just as a note you should not be having any issues with @ symbols in MS sql server because your email address should (more or less) a parameter. So this probably means you are not sending the address correctly, not that sql server has problems with "special characters".

Comment: The email should work just fine if used as a string but I don't know why it doesn't. When I send a post request with Python it executes properly using the same email and I only could trigger the "invalid email" response when the email wasn't valid, so if it isn't a problem with the email I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Can you get it working in Postman?  Also, can you tell us the API service you're using?  Is it one that we can read up documentation for or is it an internal API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually POST requests have the data sent via the Body of the request and not via the Query string. Looking at the parameters in the Query, it is highly probable that this should be sent in the **`Body`** rather than `Queries`.

If you are needing to send the email address in the Query string, then you should try Uri Encoding it.

```
uriComponent('an@email.com')
```

Comment: "Usually POST requests have the data sent via the Body of the request and not via the Query string."

This is the solution, thank you!